# Android: display recommended shorcuts in the Share sheet but hide them for app shorcuts

Tags: java, android

I am developing chat application. Currently my app can display recommended recievers in the OS share sheet to share file to specific user of my app. But I don't want these users to be displayed as app shorcuts in the menu of app in the desktop(when user long press on app icon).
My Activity has the following xml tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.service.chooser.chooser_target_service" android:resource="androidx.sharetarget.ChooserTargetServiceCompat" />
<meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts" android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
<intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

`shorcuts.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <share-target android:targetClass="sample.app.MainActivity">
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <category  android:name="sample.app.category.TEXT_SHARE_TARGET" />
    </share-target>
</shortcuts>
```

Setting dynamic shorcuts:

```
 var shortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(MainActivity.Instance, conversationID)                       
                       .setShortLabel(name)
                       .setLongLabel(name)
                       .setIcon(icon)
                       .setCategories(new[] { "sample.app.category.TEXT_SHARE_TARGET" })
                       .setLongLived(true)
                       .setIntent(intent)
                       .addCapabilityBinding("actions.intent.SEND_MESSAGE")
                       .build();
 shortcutList.add(shortcutInfo);

ShortcutManagerCompat.setDynamicShortcuts(MainActivity.Instance, shortcutList);
```

I can not display shorcuts only for share sheet.